# Select proper multithreading technique in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, performselector

I am confused on where to use which multithreading tool in iOS for hitting services and changing UI based on service data,

1. firstly I got accustomed to using NSURLConnection and its delegates, used didreceiveresponse, didreceivedata etc delegates to achieve the task
2. secondly I learned and used GCD to hit services and update the UI from within the block code
3. Now I am learning to use performSelectorInBackground() to do work in background thread

Clearly confused on which tool to use where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `NSURLConnection` with delegate calls is "old school" way of receiving data from remote server. Also it's not really comfortable to use with few NSURLConnection instances in a single class (`UIViewController` or what not). Now it's better to use `sendAsynchronousRequest..` method with completion handler. You can also define on which operation queue (main for UI, or other, background one) the completion handler will be run.
2. GCD is good for different tasks, not only fetching remote resources with `initWithContentsOfURL:` methods. You can also control what type of queues will receive your blocks (concurrent, serial ,etc.)
3. `performSelectorInBackground:` is also "old school" way of performing a method in background thread. If you weren't using ARC, you'd need to setup separate autorelease pool to avoid memory leaks. It also has a limitation of not allowing to accept arbitrary number of parameters to given selector. In this case it's recommended to use `dispatch_async`.

There are also `NSOperationQueue` with `NSOperation` and its subclasses (`NSInvocationOperation` & `NSBlockOperation`), where you can run tasks in the background as well as get notifications on main thread about finished tasks. IMHO They are more flexible than GCD in a way that you can create your own subclasses of operations as well as define dependencies between them.

Comment: you've added more to the list :) my question was where to use what; like you can say for service use sendAsynchronousRequest.. etc

Comment: I would like to know if NSOperationQueue is a universal alternative to using all others

Comment: @Firdous it would, but for simple fetch from remote server with async handler call they would be an overkill. For these tasks `sendAsynchronousRequest...` is certainly the way to go.

Comment: lets categorize the tasks 1) little fetch data from server and large changes in app in the background 2) large fetch data from server and little changes in app in the background, so NSOperationQueue for the first one and sendAsynch.. for the second one?? do u mean this?

Comment: I mean use `sendAsync...` for any request. It fetches data in the background and can run "processing" handler either in background or in main threads. NSOperationQueue can be used not only to fetch and proecss changes in the backgorund, but also when you need to send multiple requests at once.

Comment: "If you weren't using ARC, you'd need to setup separate autorelease pool to avoid memory leaks." What does ARC have to do with the need to set up an autorelease pool in the thread?

Comment: "Now it's better to use sendAsynchronousRequest.. method with completion handler." sendAsynchronousRequest is only available in iOS 5+, so you have to find another option on iOS 4

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is, that you **never** change UI anyway in another thread except the main thread.

I think, that all points you mentioned use the same technique in the background: **GDC**. But I'm not sure of that.

Anyway it doesn't matter which tool you should use in terms of threading.
It's rather a question of your purpose. If you wan't to fetch an small image or just few data you can use `contentsOfURL`in a `performSelectorInBackground()` or a GDC dispatch block.
If it's about more data and more information like progress or error handling you should stick with *NSURLConnection`.

Comment: "All points you use the same technique." Can you give a source for this claim?

Comment: Nah I can't.  It's more a guess since they said (as i remember), that they changed every threading mechanism to gdc a couple of years ago at the wwdc. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using GCD in all cases. Other techniques are still around but mainly for backward compatibility.

GCD is better for 3 reasons (at least):

1. It's extremely **easy** to use and the code remains very readable because of the use of blocks
2. It is lower level than things like NSOperation so it is **much faster** when you need high performance multi threading
3. It's lightweight and **non-intrusive** so your code doesn't have to change substantially when you want to add thread management in the middle of a method.